# How to get details about wifi connections available on my mac system through command line

Tags: macos, wifi, wireless, ssid

Currently i am working on MAC-10.9. i wanted to know the details of all wifi networks available on my system.Like 
      "SSIDName": "network_ng",
                     "DefaultAuthenticationAlgorithm": "RSNA_PSK",
                     "DefaultCipherAlgorithm": "CCMP",
                     "SecurityEnabled": "True",
                     "ConnectionStatus": "Disconnected",
                     "BssType": "Infrastructure",
                     "NetworkConnectable": "True",
                     "NumberOfSSIDs": "1",
                     "ProfileName": "",
                     "SignalQuality": "100"

just see this link http://somesite.zzl.org/PowerBASIC/WiFi.html

similarly i want wi-fi info of my mac system

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It won't give you exactly what you're looking for (some of those look like OS-specific parameters), but you can get a lot of the relevant info from the `airport` command. It's not in the default PATH, so you need to give the full path to the executable:

```
$ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s
                        SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                 myqwest0437 00:24:7b:2e:1c:01 -89  11      N  -- WPA(PSK/TKIP/TKIP) WPA2(PSK/AES/TKIP)
                     Bart2.4 04:a1:51:fc:45:97 -85  9       Y  -- WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                    Amped_SR f8:7b:8c:14:70:08 -79  2       Y  -- WPA(PSK/AES/AES) WPA2(PSK/AES/AES) 
                 NETGEAR2010 00:26:f2:c2:85:08 -85  11      Y  -- WEP
```

You can also get more detailed info about the network you're joined to with the `-I` option.

Comment: Yeah thank  you.. it is useful to some extent..I need to know exact commands to get my required information.i will do further search...

Comment: can you tell me what is the HT field in the above output @Gordon Davisson

Comment: @syammala I believe that refers to whether the network supports 802.11n "High Throughput" mode.